# Significance calculation in particle physics?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

I am wondering how does one calculate the significance of a "bump" in particle physics. Suppose I have a set of data:

for example,

in 100-200 GeV I have 700 events,

in 200-300 GeV I have 600 events,

in 300-400 GeV I have 500 events,

in 400-500 GeV I have 400 events

in 500-600 GeV I have 900 events (with background being 456)

in 600-700 GeV I have 300 events ...

Is the significance of an excess calculated by Asimov formula given in units of sigma? $$ Z_0 = \sqrt{2((s+b) \ln(1+ s/b)-s)} $$where s are the signal events and b are the background events. If no, how can I calculate it in units of sigma?

I made up the data to illustrate the question. This is not a homework or an exercise.

Comment: Your data seems a bit spotty: missing 3-400 GeV range, two sets of 1-200 GeV data. Also, $ln$ looks like the product of two variables rather than the natural log; this is written using `\ln` to indicate the operator.

Comment: maybe my answer here will help https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/480901/difference-between-expected-p-0-value-and-observed-p-0-value/480980#480980 . Particle physics uses monte carlo generated events for the background and checks against it with the usual definition of  the square root of the number of events  σ difference , peak from background.(the error in background   small)

Comment: @annav Thank you! But I still not sure I undertand the method. Could you please explain it using the data or formula I listed? I know they are related.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not relevant to particle physics because [monte carlo](https://indico.cern.ch/event/92209/contributions/2114409/attachments/1098701/1567290/CST2010-MC.pdf) generated events reduce the background errors to a line thickness as seen in this ATLAS plot of the Higgs signal in two photons:

[image]

The thick red line is a monte carlo integration of signal plus background , at the signal the background with no higgs in the calculation is given by a dashed line. The errors are one sigma calculated statistically from the square root of the number of events in each bin.

The lower plot shows the difference of measured events from monte carlo, and one can count the number of standard deviations away the bump is from the background.

That is how significance is determined usually in particle physics.

One may show more complicated probability plots with the same information but more detail, as seen in the [question here.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/480901/difference-between-expected-p-0-value-and-observed-p-0-value/480980#480980)